# Understanding three-dimensional structure of common salt

Tags: ions, atoms, crystal-structure

I started reading through The Feynman Lectures and came across this diagram. What do the numbers next to the nodes in the diagram represent? It's not explained in the text. All that is mentioned is: "Figure 1–7 is an illustration of the three-dimensional structure of common salt, sodium chloride."

[image]

A direct link to the text is [here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_01.html), just Ctrl-F "crystal of salt".

Comment: Note that 1, 3, 5, and 7 are white circles, while 2, 4, 6, and 8 are black.

Comment: Note also that they (the numbered nodes, I mean) represent the exact contents of one unit cell. Other than that, I don't think they have any meaning.

Comment: The numbering most definitely does not define a unit cell.

Comment: I never said it does. I said it represents the _contents_ of one unit cell (in one of the possible ways), and I stand by that statement.

Comment: I'm sure he wanted to explain something with the numbers, but later forgot to. What, I cannot fathom. The black and white circles each form a primitive tetrahedron. ?!?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers have three features in common:

1. Odd numbers are on one type of ion (anions) and even numbers on the other (cations).
2. Each number is at a distinct position in the periodic structure of the unit cell. For instance, the top center and bottom center anions are periodic translations of each other and thus do not represent distinct positions, so only one gets the number 5.
3. If we use (2) to put the translated numbers into one of the small cubes, we find that 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-1 follows a skew-polygonal line along the selected small cube. This may be what detetmined the ordering. The use of even and odd numbers for the two types of ion (1) is a corollary.

Comment: Anyway, if I except the point (1), it is easy to see that there are no points on the Ox and Oy axis, but one point ((2)) on the Oz axis. On the faces, there are only one point ((5)) in the Oxy plane, then 3 points ((2), (3) and (4)) on the Oxz plane, then 3 points ((2), (7), and (8)), on the Oyz plane.  Why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely no significance in the numbering of the nodes. During Feynman's lecture, he did not speak about these numbers.

A voice recording of Feynman's lecture is included on the website posted by OP. This recording is distorted in some areas, which is why a transcription is also provided.

Reading/listening to the lecture should show that this image simply served as a way to introduce solids, crystals, and in particular ions. The first lecture of "The Feynman Lectures on Physics" most likely is not going to explain crystallography or at least not in great detail.

Seeing as Feynman only specifically spoke about sodium chloride and nothing about the other salts in the legend, one can imagine that this image was not necessarily made for this lecture. The existence of the different salts and their spacing was not discussed.